# Change namespace uri in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to convert an xmi file generated by Enterprise Architect in order for it to be accepted by an eclipse tool.

One of the things I need to to change is the namespace uri for the prefix **uml:** from "http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901" to "http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML"

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" 
xmlns:uml="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901" 
xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1" >
    <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>
    <uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model">
    <!-- content of the model -->
    </uml:Model>
</xmi:XMI>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML"
xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1" >
    <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>
    <uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model">
    <!-- content of the model -->
    </uml:Model>
</xmi:XMI>
```

What I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1"
xmlns:uml="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901"
 exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- update uml:namespace to "http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML" -->
        <xsl:template match="uml:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But that removed the uml: prefix from the nodes and added a default namespace to it.

To be absolutely clear, all I need is the string

```
xmlns:uml="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901"
```

to be replaced by

```
xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML"
```

Comment: So the "expected output" should read: <xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML"...>, right?

Comment: @friedemann_bach Yes indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This produces the desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="windows-1252" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>

    <xsl:template match="uml:*" xmlns:uml="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xmi:XMI">
        <xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1"
            xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML"
            xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xmi:XMI>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am sure that there is a more simple solution. But this could be a start.

---

**Extended answer** (see question in comments): Replace the third template with this to copy all namespace declarations except `xmlns:uml`.

```
<xsl:template match="xmi:XMI">
    <xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace-node()[not(. = 'http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20090901')]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xmi:XMI>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, that indeed does the trick for this example. The problem is that the actual xml files I will need to transform have a variable number of different namespaces declarations. Would you know any way to change only the uml: namespace and leaving all other namespaces as they are?

Comment: Updated, see expanded answer.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that, but I still only get the xmi: and uml: namespace declarations and none of the other namespace declaration. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it should read `namespace-node()` instead of `@*`. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks! That did it!

Answer (score 2):

Replace `name="{local-name()}"` by `name="uml:{local-name()}"`

If you don't specify a prefix, the system won't use one.

Comment: Right, that is what I meant by "more simple solution" ;)

Comment: Unfortunately this only changes all element using the uml namespace, but it leaves the namespace declaration in the root node as is. I'm actually looking to update the namespace declaration in the root node without touching the other nodes or namespace declarations.

Comment: You say you don't want to "touch" any other nodes, but actually you want to rename them all to be in a different namespace! Remember you're not processing lexical XML as written, you're processing a tree in the XDM tree model, and in that model, the namespace has been expanded into all the affected elements. If you want to get rid of an unwanted and unused namespace declaration, in XSLT 2.0 use xsl:copy/@copy-namespaces="no"; in 1.0 use xsl:element in place of xsl:copy.